# Couldn't install gem - extconf.rb failed

Tags: ruby, macos-mojave

I upgraded the macos to Mojave and reinstalled xcode, xcode CLT, ruby, etc. Then when I tried:

```
gem install nokogiri
```

I got the following error (installing other gems gave similar error):

```
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.5/ext/nokogiri
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20181209-20884-etfc5r.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

I checked the `mkmf.log`, which contains the following:

```
"clang -o conftest -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.3_1/include/ruby-2.5.0/x86_64-darwin18 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.3_1/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.3_1/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.3_1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib     -lruby.2.5.3  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
In file included from conftest.c:1:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.3_1/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby.h:33:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.3_1/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/ruby.h:29:
```

The text went on like this for a while. I also `cd` to the nokogiri folder and directly run `extconf.rb`, and got the following error:

```
checking if the C compiler accepts ... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.`

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
```

... (skipped similar content for brevity and continued below)

```
usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.3_1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:456:in 'try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
```

I tried to install xcode. I also installed the header and acknowledged the license. I at first thought it has to do with GCC, but the mkmf file showed that the problem is with `Clang`.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Can you confirm you have Xcode Command Line tools installed?

Comment: Hi Greg, I ran `xcode-select --install` and saw this: `xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`. So that means it's already installed, right? Thanks!

Comment: what's the output of ```/usr/bin/clang```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? `~ :)/usr/bin/clang
clang: error: no input files`

Answer (score 0):

I had to run the following cryptic commands to get nokogiri installed. Basically this entails getting my C compiler working in mac osx Mojave, after having everything working fine in a previous OS (Yosemite I think it was...)

This is an (somewhat) obvious step when upgrading osx:

```sh
xcode-select --install
```

I also had to do this, which I never would've known how to do without google and [this post](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.14-mojave)

```sh
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
```

Finally, I had to agree to the xcode license (found I had to do this via the makefile logs when install of nokogiri failed...)

```sh
sudo xcodebuild -licence
```

It'll prompt you to eventually type "agree"

Finally, continuing with `bundle` works as expected for a new rails project that includes nokogiri. Success!